# Servlet doesn't go to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When i am my ConfirmServlet at the end of the doPost() it should open my ResultServlet. But instead the link stays /Confirm at the end and i get a blank page. Could anyone help me whats wrong with my code.

***ConfirmServlet***

```
package Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import Bean.SurveyBean;
import DAO.DriverLoader;
import DAO.SurveyDAO;
import Service.SurveyService;

@WebServlet(value = "/Confirm", initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name = "Confirmpage", value = "/WEB-INF/pages/Confirm.jsp"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "ResultURL", value = "Result") })
public class ConfirmServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String Confirmpage;
    private String ResultURL;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        new DriverLoader();
        Confirmpage = getInitParameter("Confirmpage");
        ResultURL = getInitParameter(ResultURL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SurveyBean bean = new SurveyBean();
        HttpSession sess = req.getSession();
        bean = (SurveyBean) sess.getAttribute("bean");
        req.setAttribute("bean", bean);
        System.out.println(bean.getName() + " " + bean.getAnswer3() + " haha");
        System.out.println("Testing");
        req.getRequestDispatcher(Confirmpage).forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Post Werkt");
        HttpSession sess = req.getSession();
        SurveyBean bean = new SurveyBean();
        bean = (SurveyBean) sess.getAttribute("bean");
        SurveyDAO Dao;
        Dao = new SurveyDAO("jdbc:mysql://localhost/survey", "root", "");
        Dao.postBean(bean);


        resp.sendRedirect(ResultURL);
        System.out.println("Hier moet ik ook komen!!!");
    }

}
```

***ResultServlet***

```
package Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Bean.SurveyBean;

@WebServlet(value = "/Result", initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name = "ResultPage", value = "/WEB-INF/pages/Result.jsp"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "IndexURL", value = "IndexURL") })
public class ResultServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String ResultPage;
    private String IndexURL;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Result");
        super.init();
        ResultPage = getInitParameter(ResultPage);
        IndexURL = getInitParameter(IndexURL);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Doget Result");
        req.getRequestDispatcher(ResultPage).forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resp.sendRedirect(IndexURL);
    }


}
```

Btw i used the same code for the previous routes and there it worked only here i get a error and i have no idea wich one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here Had to add " at getInitParameter. At both Servlets

```
@Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.init();
        new DriverLoader();
        Confirmpage = getInitParameter("Confirmpage");
        ResultURL = getInitParameter("ResultURL");
    }
```